Comparison of two random function generators
I need to evaluate two random function generators. Both are supposed to generate random functions from a given Gaussian process prior (SE-ARD kernel) with a known mean function and covariance function.
I suspect one of the two generators to generate functions that are "too smooth", that is, functions with a longer effective length scale than the gaussian prior. How may I check if this is correct and which function generator provides the more "appropriate" random functions from the Gaussian prior? Both function generators work numerically.
